# Best way to populate javaFX TableView from programatically defined structure

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, tableview

I have here a relatively complex Java CRUD written with Swing components. I'm thinking about re-writting GUI of it in JavaFX. Now here's the problem:

I've made a class that is used for saving the downloaded data, storing the SQL commands and some other information about any given table. I define the data structure of that table in constructor of it. Like this:

```
    vyrData = new KTable(
        "manufacturers",                      //Name of the table
        "select * from manufacturers ",       //SQL select of it
        " order by name ",                    //Ordering
        "",                                   //Limiting
        new String[]    {"id", "name"},       //Column names in database
        null,                                 //Column names for GUI (if differ from db ones)
        new Class<?>[]  {Long.class, String.class}, //Column types
        false,                                // ...if the table should be limited by size.
        false                                 // ...if the table should be read in reverse order
        );
```

This way I don't have to touch the code of this class whenever the database table structure changes. I'll just mirror the change in the constructor and edit GUI accordingly.

(Inside the class, the data are stored as ArrayList. Probably not the cleanest solution, but worked nicely. Object[][] would also do I guess.)

Now, JavaFX TableView uses observable list, which is idea I like for refreshing reasons, but every tutorial I've seen so far is feeding it with a custom data objects with hardcoded property names, setters and getters. That contradicts with the idea of one class being used to store any table.

Is it possible to somehow generate data structure programatically, yet still use observable list? If not, what's the easiest solution to populete the teble from 2D array?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28731598/setcellvaluefactory-for-dynamic-number-of-column-in-javafx

Answer (score 0):

You can use any data structure you want to store the data, but you should keep the following in mind:

- You need one item per row in the `TableView`. These items may be the data itself or simply a key used to look the data up in a custom data structure.
- Retrieving the cell values should be efficient.
- The cells of the `TableView` need to be aware of changes to the underlying data structure. (This could be a problem, since you use a `ArrayList`)

The `TableColumn`'s [`cellValueFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.html#cellValueFactoryProperty) is used to retrieve the data displayed in a table cell. You can use it to retrieve your data given the `TableView` item. Note that it has to return [`ObservableValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/value/ObservableValue.html) and a listener will be registered to the return value that expects to be notified, if the data changes.

In the following example stores the data in a `ObservableMap<Integer, ObservableList<Object>>` to demonstrate this (key = ID, list contains other column values)

```
public static ObservableMap<Long, ObservableList<Object>> createData(long[] ids, Object[][] values) {
    ObservableMap<Long, ObservableList<Object>> map = FXCollections.observableHashMap();
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        map.put(ids[i], FXCollections.observableArrayList(values[i]));
    }
    return map;
}
```

```
    ObservableMap<Long, ObservableList<Object>> data = createData(
            new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4},
            new Object[][]{
                new Object[]{"John Doe"},
                new Object[]{"Leia Organa"},
                new Object[]{"Nathasha Romanov"},
                new Object[]{"Tony Stark"}
            });

    // list of map keys
    ObservableList<Long> rowIDs = FXCollections.observableArrayList(data.keySet());
    data.addListener((MapChangeListener<Long, ObservableList<Object>>) (m -> {
        if (m.wasAdded()) {
            rowIDs.add(m.getKey());
        }
        if (m.wasRemoved()) {
            rowIDs.remove(m.getKey());
        }
    }));

    TableView<Long> tv = new TableView<>(rowIDs);

    // column displaying the ID
    TableColumn<Long, Long> idColumn = new TableColumn<>("id");
    idColumn.setCellValueFactory(c -> Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> c.getValue()));

    tv.getColumns()
            .setAll(idColumn,
                    createColumn("name", (index) -> Bindings.valueAt(data.get(index), 0)));
```

```
public static <I, O> TableColumn<I, O> createColumn(String columnName, Function<I, ObservableValue<O>> valueGetter) {
    TableColumn<I, O> column = new TableColumn<>(columnName);
    column.setCellValueFactory(c -> {
        I item = c.getValue();
        return valueGetter.apply(item);
    });
    return column;
}
```

This may be more complex than you need... It would be much simpler to simply store the rows as `ObservableList`s (or `Object[]`/`List<Object>`, if a row's column values are not modified but rows are replaced completely instead):

```
TableView<ObservableList<Object>> tv = new TableView<>();
tv.getItems().setAll(FXCollections.observableArrayList(1, "John Doe"),
        FXCollections.observableArrayList(2, "Leia Organa"),
        FXCollections.observableArrayList(3, "Nathasha Romanov"),
        FXCollections.observableArrayList(4, "Tony Stark"));

// columns created using createColumn(<column name>, l -> Bindings.valueAt(l, <data index>))
tv.getColumns().setAll(createColumn("id", l -> Bindings.valueAt(l, 0)),
        createColumn("name", l -> Bindings.valueAt(l, 1)));
```

As you can see, it's easy to create table columns in both cases, given the array containing column names (using a loop).

Comment: Ok thanks so much for help. I think now my actual problem is that despite all effort and tutorial reading I do not understand lambda expressions at all. As much as I'd love to learn them, all tries failed. Thus, is it possible to fill the table without use of lambda expressions? For example with some interfaces.

Comment: @user3707953: Lambda expressions are not that complicated. But you can easily convert them to anonymus classes following these steps: Given: lambda expression  `<parameters> -> <body>` which is assigned to funcional interface `I`. 1. Replace the lambda expression with anonymus class implementing `I`. 2. Rename parameters of the method in `I` to match `<parameters>`. 3. Copy `<body>` to the method body and add `return`, if the lambda body is not enclosed in `{}`. 4. Fix all references using `this` in the method body, if necessary (using `ContainingClass.this` instead).